# Apache Flink and Dividing a job to tasks

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, job-scheduling, flink-batch

I have an apache flink related question. Currently I am investigating apache flink for as our jobs framework.

Essentially we have a content ingestion job where we ingest some contents from a feed, which is paginated in nature. the content of the feed can be in xml or json and per page can have 1000 records.

What I do need is to take those 1000 records are divide up into tasks and parallelize its processing.

I understand that flink has some way to parallelize its jobs but dividing up into Task slots.
I wanted to know how we can do it or any online resources will be appreciated.

I saw that we can set up using setParallelism(), but i had a hard time finding a way to set up the processing.

So just to give you an idea.. here is a sample feed

```
<mainTag>
    <subTag>
    ......
    </subTag>
    <subTag>
    ......
    </subTag>
    <subTag>
    ....
    </subTag>
</mainTag>
```

Now here in the above xml sample I want to divide the the  and process it parallely.

This is analogous to how we use an ExecutorService in java for multi-threaded processing.

In plain java i would do executorService.submit(subtagTask) to process the subTag.

I wanted to know if in Flink there is a way to do that. It would help me not have the headache of handling threads and the headache that comes with it.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The good news: Flink was especially built to run stuff in parallel without you worrying about threads or other things. In most cases, you use Flink when it comes to scaling out (= using more than one machine). However, scaling up (more threads per one machine) is a valid use case. Just be aware that there may be other simpler options.

The bad news: there is no out-of-the-box support for XML. It's not too hard to add but that's probably what you are looking for. JSON is directly supported but also not for full files afaik. The main reason is that Flink is originally a stream processor and is still in the progress of transitioning into a unified/batch processor.

So I guess, in your case it would be better to evaluate alternatives (e.g. Spark) for now. Flink still needs to catch up in the next couple of releases in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for your input, adding xml or json suport would not be tough. I am more interested in parallelism and its connectors. are there any resources that shows how to do that based on my use case